# https and non-www redirecting in htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I have that htacces code, which is redirecting all pages without "www" to "www", except the main page. Also this code is redirecting all pages with "http" to "https", when I try to go for example to some page with "http" and It always ends on `index.php`

My code is here:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?beautypetra\.cz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beautypetra.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.beautypetra.cz/$1 [L,R=301]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://www.beautypetra.cz/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you please better explain what the expected vs actual behaviour is?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community @Matus. I have provided the working example. If it solves your problem do let the other SO user knows by accepting it through clicking the right button near the answer. In case you are struggling with the solution,leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In htaccess you can have the rewriting of non-www url to www url and http to https with the below rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beautypetra.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.beautypetra.cz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In this `OR` clause is used so that a single rule can be used.

The above rule redirects all combination of `http` and `www` to `https://www` one url.
Tested the code for the same.

[.htaccess tester result](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=3131d6c0-da9f-5931-b312-9657aeff1a24)